# How to refresh list in react when items are manipulated from outside

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-context

I am new to React Native and I try to implement a "reset feature" in my game.
And allthough the game data is reset correctly I can't find out how to rerender the components that are displaying the elements...

*Note: some components have been simplified, but they should still reflect the purpose*

My `gameData` is structured as follows:

```js
{
    "puzzles" : [
        { "id": 0, "icon": "0", "codes": ["abc], "unlocked": true },
        { "id": 1, "icon": "1", "codes": ["def"] },
        { "id": 2, "icon": "2", "codes": ["ghi"] }
    ]
}
```

so the types for this are

```js
export type GameData = {
    puzzles: Puzzle[],
}

export type Puzzle = {
    id: number,
    icon: string,
    codes: string[],
    unlocked: boolean,
};
```

In my game I create a `gameContext` that allows unlocking the individual `Puzzle`s and (if you want to start over) resetting the state. Therefore I initially load the `gameData` from a json and from there on I save the unlocked states in the `AsyncStorage` (for a better overview I removed the save & load part - this works fine):

```js
const jsonGameData: GameData = require('./gamedata.json');

export const GameContext = createContext({
    gameData: undefined as GameData | undefined,
    unlockHint: async (item: Hint) => { },
    unlockPuzzle: async (item: Puzzle) => { },
    loadProgress: async () => { },
    resetProgress: async () => { }
});

async function saveItemState(type: string, id: number, unlocked: boolean) {
    let key = type + "." + id;
    console.log("save " + key + "=" + String(unlocked));
    return AsyncStorage.setItem(key, String(unlocked))
};

export const GameContextProvider = ({ children } : { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
    const [gameData, setGameData] = useState<GameData>(jsonGameData)
    const [progressLoaded, setProgressLoaded] = useState(false);

    async function unlockPuzzle(item: Puzzle) {
        item.unlocked = true;
        console.log("puzzle unlocked: " + JSON.stringify(item));
        return saveItemState("puzzle", item.id, true).then( () => {
            setGameData(gameData);
        });
    };

    async function loadProgress() {      
        if(progressLoaded)
            return;
        console.log("loading progress");
        const promises = gameData.puzzles.map((item : Puzzle, index: Number) => {
            return loadItemState("puzzle", item.id).then(unlocked => {
                item.unlocked ||= unlocked;
                console.log("puzzle." + item.id + "=" + item.unlocked);
            });
        });      
        return Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
            setGameData(gameData);
            setProgressLoaded(true);
        });
    };

    async function resetProgress() {
        console.log("reset progress");
        const promises = gameData.puzzles.map((item : Puzzle) => {
            item.unlocked = false;
            return saveItemState("puzzle", item.id, item.unlocked);
        });
        return Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
            setGameData(gameData);
        });
    };

    return  <GameContext.Provider value={{
                gameData,
                unlockHint,
                unlockPuzzle,
                loadProgress,
                resetProgress
            }}>
                {children}
            </GameContext.Provider>
};
```

Now I created a `PuzzleCard` component to render the `Puzzle` items:

```js
export type PuzzleCardProps = {item: Puzzle} & View['props'];
export function PuzzleCard(props: PuzzleCardProps) {
    const { gameData, unlockPuzzle } = useContext(GameContext);
    const { item, ...otherProps } = props;  
    const [unlocked, setUnlocked] = useState(item.unlocked);
    const handlePress = function() {
        unlockPuzzle(item).then(() => {
            setUnlocked(true);
        });
    };
    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log("gameData updated"); // does not trigger
    }, [gameData]);
    return  <Pressable onPress={handlePress} style={styles.card}>
                <Text style={styles.cardIcon}>{item.icon}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.cardState}>{unlocked ? "" : ""}</Text>
            </Pressable>;
}
```

and added these items to a list on a tab in my application:

```js
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {gameData.puzzles.map((puzzle: Puzzle, index: number) => {
                return  <PuzzleCard key={index} item={puzzle}/>
            })}
        </View>
```

**Everything works fine so far:** If the `PuzzleCard` is clicked, then

1. the matching `Puzzle` item is unlocked
2. the state is stored to `AsyncStorage`
3. the `PuzzleCard` is updated (the state changes from "" to "")

Now I want to add a button on a different view in the application to reset the progress, when the player wants to start all over:

```js
export function ResetButton() {
    const { resetProgress } = useContext(GameContext);
    return <Pressable onPress={resetProgress}>Reset</Pressable>
}
```

Resetting works as intended (in the background)

1. all `Puzzle` items are locked
2. the state is stored to `AsyncStorage`

**But**

3. the list of `PuzzleCard`s is **NOT updated** (state remains "")

If I reload the app / refresh the browser, all items are rerendered and displayed correctly with the new (reset) state.

**How can I make sure, that my app rerenders to reflect the changes?** (without the need of a reload)

Comment: What does the `saveItemState` function do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some playing around I finally came up with a solution that works for me

Note: the solutions is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/76264763/4090157 but I modified it to use `useState` for the `puzzles` Array only (instead of the whole `gameData`) to avoid re-renders of components that are not affected. Thanks @Xiduzo

I create the `GameContext` as follows

```js
const jsonGameData: GameData = require('./gamedata.json');

export const GameContext = createContext({
    puzzles: undefined as Puzzle[] | undefined,
    unlockPuzzle: async (id: number) => { },
    resetProgress: async () => { }
});

export const GameContextProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
    const [puzzles, setPuzzles] = useState(jsonGameData.puzzles);

    // init
    useEffect(() => {
        async function initAsync() {
            console.log("initializing GameContext");
            Promise.all(puzzles.map((item: Puzzle, index: Number) => {
                return loadItemState("puzzle", item.id).then(unlocked => ({
                    ...item,
                    unlocked: item.unlocked || unlocked
                }));
            })).then((newItems) => {
                setPuzzles(newItems);
            });
        }

        initAsync();
    }, []);

    async function unlockPuzzle(id: number) {
        console.log("unlocking puzzle #" + id);
        return saveItemState("puzzle", id, true).then(() => {
            console.log("set puzzles (#" + id + ")");
            let newItem = {
                ...puzzles[id],
                unlocked: true,
            };
            // Setting the state will trigger a re-render of your components
            setPuzzles(puzzles.map((item: Puzzle, i: number) => (i == id ? newItem : item)));
        });
    };

    async function resetProgress() {
        console.log("reset progress");
        Promise.all(puzzles.map((item: Puzzle) => {
            return removeItemState("puzzle", item.id).then(() => ({
                ...item,
                unlocked: jsonGameData.puzzles[item.id].unlocked
            }));
        })).then((newItems) => {
            setPuzzles(newItems);
        });
    };

    return <GameContext.Provider value={{
        puzzles,
        unlockPuzzle,
        resetProgress
    }}>
        {children}
    </GameContext.Provider>
};
```

The `PuzzleCard` component was updated as follows:

```js
export type PuzzleCardProps = {item: Puzzle} & View['props'];
export function PuzzleCard(props: PuzzleCardProps) {
    const { unlockPuzzle } = useContext(GameContext);
    const { item, ...otherProps } = props;  
    const handlePress = function() {
        unlockPuzzle(item.id);
    };
    return  <Pressable onPress={handlePress} style={styles.card}>
                <Text style={styles.cardIcon}>{item.icon}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.cardState}>{item.unlocked ? "" : ""}</Text>
                <Text>{JSON.stringify(item)}</Text>
            </Pressable>;
}
```

And the list of `PuzzleCard`s is now using the newly created context:

```js
export default function Puzzles({ navigation }: RootTabScreenProps<'Puzzles'>) {    
    const { puzzles } = useContext(GameContext);
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {puzzles != null ? puzzles.map((puzzle: Puzzle, index: number) => {
                return  <PuzzleCard key={index} item={puzzle}/>
            }) : <Text>no game data loaded</Text>}
        </View>
    );
}
```

So that finally the `ResetButton` works as expected:

```js
export function ResetButton() {
    const { resetProgress } = useContext(GameContext);
    return <Pressable onPress={resetProgress}>Reset</Pressable>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are not fully understanding the use of `context` within React. Your `gameData` is not stateful and therefore will not trigger any re-render of any components relying on it.

```
const jsonGameData: GameData = require('./gamedata.json');

const GameContext = createContext({
 gameData: undefined as GameData | undefined,
 unlockPuzzle: async (item: Puzzle) => { },
 ...yourOtherMethods
})

const GameContextProvider = ({ children } : { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
   const [gameData, setGameData] = useState<GameData>(jsonGameData)

   async function unlockPuzzle(item: Puzzle) {
     item.unlocked = true;
     // save to AsyncStorage, Make sure to return the new state
     return saveItemState("hint", item.id, true).then( (newState) => {
        console.log("set gameData");
        // Setting the state will trigger a re-render of your components
        setGameData(newState);
     });
   };

 return <GameContext.Provider value={{
   gameData,
   unlockPuzzle,
   ...yourOtherMethods
  }}>
   {children}
 </GameContext.Provider>
}
```

```
// App.tsx

const App = () => {
 <GameContextProvider>
  // ... your app

 </GameContextProvider>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Xiduzo. You're right: I really don't fully understand the use of `context` in React, but at least with some minor changes to your code (sorry, but the edit queue is currently full), I was able to create & use the context. However I still encounter the issue, that the UI is not re-rendered on `resetProgress`, although I call `setGameData` from within that function.

Comment: What I don't understand / am unsure about: is it really required to return `newState` from `saveItemState`? (Because this is complicated, because I just pass the item state to that method and the storage does not contain the complete `gameData`...) Or couldn't I just update gameData with itself: `setGameData(gameData)`?

Comment: PS: I would have updated your answer with the minor changes, but the edit queue is currently full...

Comment: Update: @Xiduzo: I edited your answer to reflect my async behavior. However I still struggle with the `newState`.  Instead of returning a `newState` from `saveItemState`, I tried to update it using
`setGameData(gameData => ({ hints: gameData.hints, puzzles: gameData.puzzles.map(item => (item.id == itemId ? { ...item, unlocked: true, } : item)) }));` - and this is successfully triggering the `useEffect` *gameData updated* (see question) but in the same instance it lets my browser tab freeze... 

Answer (score 0):

In your context you should use a state to store the data you send, so the updates can be hooked by the components using it.

For example, you can use a state for `gameData`

```
const [gameData, setGameData] = useState(require('./gamedata.json'));
```

Then update it with the `setGameData` function

```
async function resetProgress() {
  setGameData({
    ...gameData,
    puzzles: gameData.puzzles.map((item) => {
      item.unlocked = false;
      saveItemState("puzzle", item.id, item.unlocked); 
      return item;
    });
  });
};
```

That way, the parts of the template that render the data of `gameData` context will be updated everytime `setGameData` is called.

Does this approach suit you ?

Comment: Hey, I tried adding useState to my `game` initialization as proposed and although it compiles, it unfortunately doesn't work and I receive an error *Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. T* in the browser.

Comment: Ah sorry i didn't realised but the game function must be function returning a React component, it is the only way to have a state and to trigger re-render. The answer by ultimate explain how to create a transform your game function to a real `context`, you will then be able to use my solution